`export` doesn't appear in `~/bashrc`
I want to install a LAMMPS software simulator, and I'm doing the same steps outlined in this video: https://youtu.be/-cYhA2wFGWs,
but when I try to add the export to ~/.bashrc the rest of the code doesn't appear.
This is the last thing that appears:
# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

How can i add the export?
This is a screenshot of the video:


The snippet that appears after the snippet you posted, before the export line that you're supposed to add (at around 5:47), is setting up a conda environment, and is not part of the default ~/.bashrc; so, whoever shot the video tutorial had added it to ~/.bashrc themselves;
Looking at the written version of the tutorial it's mentioned nowhere that a conda environment should be set up at some point.
From this I conclude that, simply, whoever shot the video had that snippet in their ~/.bashrc already, before shooting the video, for other reasons.
So you don't need that snippet in your ~/.bashrc at all, and you can just add your export line at the end of your current ~/.bashrc (replace /path/to/lammps/bin with the correct path):
export PATH="${PATH}:/path/to/lammps/bin"


thank you .i did it and it's working now

If one of the answers here solved your issue, @HAIDARABBAS, please take a moment and accept it by clicking on the checkmark on the left. That is the best way to express your thanks on the Stack Exchange sites.
